# apache web server performance with mod_headers, mod_filters and mod_expires in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have been using Pingdom to do some analysis of my website performance and to monitor loading speed along with any other issues that my arise.

I noticed that I had some opportunities to speed-up performance of my site by compressing the data that is being requested and delivered.

My first step was to use my `.htaccess` file to set up what I wanted to cache and compress. Using the H5PB as my starting point, I added this to my file:

```
# ######################################################################
# # WEB PERFORMANCE                                                    #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Compression                                                        |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    #
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding
    # https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/pushing-beyond-gzipping/

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    #
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                      "application/javascript" \
                                      "application/json" \
                                      "application/ld+json" \
                                      "application/manifest+json" \
                                      "application/rdf+xml" \
                                      "application/rss+xml" \
                                      "application/schema+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                      "application/wasm" \
                                      "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                      "application/x-javascript" \
                                      "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                      "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                      "application/xml" \
                                      "font/collection" \
                                      "font/eot" \
                                      "font/opentype" \
                                      "font/otf" \
                                      "font/ttf" \
                                      "image/bmp" \
                                      "image/svg+xml" \
                                      "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                      "image/x-icon" \
                                      "text/cache-manifest" \
                                      "text/calendar" \
                                      "text/css" \
                                      "text/html" \
                                      "text/javascript" \
                                      "text/plain" \
                                      "text/markdown" \
                                      "text/vcard" \
                                      "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                      "text/vtt" \
                                      "text/x-component" \
                                      "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                      "text/xml"

</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | ETags                                                              |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Remove `ETags` as resources are sent with far-future expires headers.
#
# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag
# https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
# https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.3

# `FileETag None` doesn't work in all cases.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header unset ETag

    <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|gif|swf|eot|woff|otf|ttf|svg)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </filesmatch>
    <filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1209600, public"
    </filesmatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
    </filesMatch>

</IfModule>

FileETag None

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Cache expiration                                                   |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve resources with far-future expiration date.
#
# (!) If you don't control versioning with filename-based
# cache busting, you should consider lowering the cache times
# to something like one week.
#
# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control
# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"


  # Data interchange

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/calendar                         "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images

    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML

    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"


  # JavaScript

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"


  # Manifest files

    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Markdown

    ExpiresByType text/markdown                         "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Media files

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"


  # WebAssembly

    ExpiresByType application/wasm                      "access plus 1 year"


  # Web fonts

    # Collection
    ExpiresByType font/collection                       "access plus 1 month"

    # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

    # OpenType
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/otf                              "access plus 1 month"

    # TrueType
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf                              "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2                            "access plus 1 month"


  # Other

    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>
```

After reviewing how my site responded to these changes and how it effected my performance, I noticed that I was still getting these suggestions on my site:

```
F 0
Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)

F 1
Add Expires headers

F 34
Configure entity tags (ETags)

D 67
Compress components with gzip

B 80
Make fewer HTTP requests

B 80
Use cookie-free domains

B 85
Reduce DNS lookups
```

Next, I started to look at if I needed to alter some of my headers being sent in php within my dynamic files, so added this to all of my html/php files:

```
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
```

And this to all of my css/js files:

```
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 86400) . ' GMT');
```

I even went to far as to minify my CSS/JS and output HTML from PHP and to reduce the load of HTTP calls, base64_encoded images being rendered in the UI.

Overall, I have been able to reduce the main payload of my HTML/CSS/JS (yay!), however, my performance grade are still in the dumps:

```
Performance grade
C79/100

Load time
2.21S

Page size
1.37MB

Requests
21
```

Any thoughts around what I may be doing wrong, or where I can look to next to try and get that 2.21S down? Or if I even have the possibility of getting that 1.37MB down?

Comment: You're using Apache - that's your first bottleneck. If you are using `mod_php` instead of fastcgi to speak to PHP, that's your second and the worst bottleneck. If you're after speed, dumping Apache for nginx would shave off a lot. You can fiddle with random header settings, they're mostly meaningless. Performance gain is done by optimizing the http stack (web server) and doing least possible work in backend stack (PHP and whatever db / processing you got going on). Everything else is going to be a lot of time spent to gain negligible performance.

Comment: That's fair. Unfortunately, for now, this project is stuck using Apache/2.4.18 (Unix). We are using FASTCGI for PHP.